# .htaccess called specific page when matching contain words in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've doubt about how to create .htaccess of the page url that containing specific words to using a performance from index.php.

I'm not meant about redirecting 301 to index.php.

But I want to access url such as /my-account/lost-password/index.html or /my-account/create/index.html. And when visit both url, it would be called content from index.php without redirecting to index.php.

Is it possible to write .htaccess to working with above requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /lost-password/index.html
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Assuming you'd put this in the htaccess file in your `my-account` folder.